# Глаголы спустить-спуститься и опустить-опуститься — различие в употреблении

Tags: лексика

Глаголы спустить-спуститься и опустить-опуститься: в чем различия, есть ли какие-то правила употребления, могут ли быть синонимами?

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите на Грамоте значения ([спустить](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x), [опустить](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)). Их много. Пересекаются они в первых значениях (синонимы): *спустить/опустить флаг, ребёнка на пол.* И то, опускают обычно ***на что-то***, а спускают ***откуда-то*** иногда с указанием *на что,* а иногда и *без.* Так что лучше всё-таки не пропускать этого указания, как в примере: *спустить ребёнка **с рук** на пол.*

Ещё у *"спустить"* есть значение *стянуть вниз* какую-то одежду или часть одежды, которого нету у *"опустить".*

*"[Спуститься](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&all=x)"* и *"[опуститься](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&all=x)"* тоже употребляются и с совпадающими, и с разными предлогами. Однако интересно, что *опуститься* можно ***на что-то***, например *на дно,* а *спуститься — **на чём-то**,* например *на лыжах, на лифте.* Кроме того, при *опускании* важен результат — *на что,* поэтому не говорят *опустить(ся) **с чего-то**,* а *спустить(ся)* — пожалуйста: *спуститься с гор, спустить кого-то с лестницы.*